# append() shows unexpected behavior when concatenating "unfinished" markup

Tags: jquery, html

So I have some Data from the DB which I want to display in a multilevel dropdown menu. 
The idea is that products can be accessed through their categories, like this:
Overallmenu -> Manufacturermenu -> Manufacturer -> Products

To do this, I'm using several loops to iterate over the JSON parsed, multidimensional JS Object containing the Data. 
The loops work, the data is also inserted in the desired order (for example, after manufacturer A has been inserted, all the products related to manufacturer A are inserted, then manufacturer B is inserted and so on).

However, it seems that append() gives me some trouble. 
Here is the loop structure so far:

```
function setAllProductsWithCategorisation(id, allProductsByCategorisation){
    console.log("inside setAllProductsWithCategorisation",allProductsByCategorisation)
    Object.keys(allProductsByCategorisation).forEach((category) => {
      //console.log(category)

      $('#' + id).append("<li><a href='#'>" + category + "</a><ul class='vertical menu nested'><select>")

      allProductsByCategorisation[category].forEach((product) => {
        //console.log(product)
        $('#' + id).append("<option value=" + product + ">" + product + "</option>")
      })


      $('#' + id).append("</select></ul></li>")

  })
}
```

Now, after the process has finished, all the options are located OUTSIDE their respective select elements. 
When inspecting the DOM with the Chrome Devtools, I found that the select element immediately closes after having been opened in my concatenation. 
It seems jquery append() is "guessing" that I just forgot to close it and therefore automatically inserts a closing bracket Oo 
Same goes for my ul element (see screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHBnn.jpg )

How can I prevent this? I basically just want to manually build this markup through nesting the loops iterating over the respective data and then add the code piece by piece. Append() was pretty awesome so far but this behavior is pretty iffy...

Comment: try `await` on `forEach` functions

Comment: This is expected behaviour - you can only append entire elements. You cannot append a `<select>` tag in one call then the `</select>` in another. As such you need to change your logic to append the entire elements, then append children to those as needed, or you need to build a HTML string in the loop and `append()` that once

Answer (score 2):

The append will continous append the elements after the last content, so.
Instead of append, you can just concatenate it to a variable then after append it.

```
 var appendHtm = '';
 appendHtm += "<li><a href='#'>" + category + "</a><ul class='vertical menu nested'><select>";

  allProductsByCategorisation[category].forEach((product) => {
    //console.log(product)
    appendHtm += "<option value=" + product + ">" + product + "</option>";
  })


  appendHtm += "</select></ul></li>";

  $('#' + id).append(appendHtm);
```

Comment: i noticed a lack of semicolons in OPs code, this will throw JS off sometimes, in most scenarios. Sanjun has added them above. one thing that makes this type of work clean is using template literals:

<li><a href='#'> ${category} </a><ul class='vertical menu nested'><select>

StackOverflow wont let me save the tick marks, but there should be tick marks around this whole line ``